# Best way to store records in database tables with common fields

Tags: mysql, database

I have several database tables such as.

- category
- brand
- color
- capacity
- carrier

Which have common column names.

- name
- alias

What is the best way to store such records ? store in spit tables or one table ? what is the standard practice ?

BTW, I am using MySQL with Doctrine ORM.

Thanks

Comment: Use two attributes for each table: despite the fact, that columns have same names (and meaning) - they still belong to __different__ entities - and, therefore, for example, `category.name` has _nothing to do_ with `color.name`. Store them as they are. Do not use EAV-like structure (check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20782760/difference-between-two-table-structure/20783125#20783125) to understand reasons)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thinking about scalability,performance and new enhanced features(like LINQ) integration;  store in split tables and identifying with foreign key  will be much better choice.

Eg: You can integrate searching with better performance speed. The re usability will be also good as, if you want to add an item in future, will not be caused the existing data.