# How can I 'order by' non normalized column? And composite order by

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table `documents` table `keywords`. Each document can have any quantity of keywords.

Keyword examples:

`Client Name`,
`Billing period`,
`Client Address`, etc.

It must be noted that document can have any keyword on it, so it cannot be normalized (its just metadata).

Now I want to order, for example, by `Client Name` and then by `Billing Period`, how can I do?

If I make `Select * from Keywords group by keyword order by value` I don't get what I need. I don't have much experience with MySQL so I couldn't do much more.

Example with test data:

```
+-------+-------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| id    | document_id | keyword              | value                |
+-------+-------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   265 |          89 | Nº de Operacion     | 000534556315         |
| 15708 |        5234 | Direccion IP         | 192.168.100.168      |
|   267 |          89 | Fecha                | 20131021             |
| 15760 |        5240 | Nombre de Cliente    | CLIENTEN1            |
| 15761 |        5240 | Asunto               | DEMANDACESTADO1220   |
| 15703 |        5234 |                      | DEMANDACESTADO1220   |
| 15700 |        5234 | Nombre de Legajo     | Documento            |
| 15702 |        5234 | Nombre del Documento | Documento            |
| 15701 |        5234 | Tipo de Documento    | Documento            |
| 15842 |        5256 | Descripcion          | ffff                 |
| 15709 |        5234 | Localizacion         | No definida          |
| 15707 |        5234 | Grupo Usuario        | Operadores           |
|   266 |          89 | Socio                | Socio1               |
| 15835 |        5255 | Decripcion           | sadsdf               |
| 15704 |        5234 | ID de Usuario        | ssadmin              |
| 15706 |        5234 | Nombre de Usuario    | ssadmin              |
+-------+-------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

Tables

```
mysql> describe documents;
+---------+-----------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field   | Type      | Null | Key | Default             | Extra                       |
+---------+-----------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
| id      | int(11)   | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment              |
| name    | char(100) | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| wfid    | char(50)  | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| docid   | char(50)  | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| created | timestamp | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                             |
| updated | timestamp | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+---------+-----------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe keywords;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| document_id | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| keyword     | char(50)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| value       | varchar(250) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: What do you get with the query you show? `Select * from Keywords group by keyword order by value` . It's better if you write it completely in your question.

Comment: As I understand OP is asking to dynamically order by a values (from keywords.keyword)

Comment: Your structure is well-known as EAV. It's bad choice in vast majority of cases in context of relational DB. Reasons for this I've described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20783125/2637490).

Comment: @AlmaDo what would you recommend to do in this case? Documents are not fixed metadata, they can have other key-value pairs as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Your "keywords" are not keywords.  They are attribute-value pairs.  This style of data storage is called "Entity-Attribute-Value" (abbreviated to EAV).  I would not recommend using it for attributes that are on every document.

In any case, it is what you have.  You can do what you want using aggregation with conditional aggregation:

```
select document_id,
       max(case when keyword = 'Client Name' then value end) as ClientName,
       max(case when keyword = 'Billing Period' then value end) as BillingPeriod
from keywords
group by document_id
order by ClientName, BillingPeriod;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear whether you might have more than one Client Name and/or more than one Billing Period for each doc. If you did then the following would achieve what you want.  However, as others have said, this is a very poor way to store structured information in a database.

```
select d.id, cn.ClientName, bp.BillingPeriod from documents d
left join (select document_id, value as ClientName from keywords where keyword = 'Client Name') cn on d.id = cn.document_id
left join (select document_id, value as BillingPeriod from keywords where keyword = 'Billing Period') bp on d.id = bp.document_id
group by name, cn.ClientName, bp.BillingPeriod, d.id
order by cn.ClientName, bp.BillingPeriod
```

Comment: Hi, documents will have only one key with example "Customer Name", keys are not duplicated for each document.

Comment: Then I recommend you enforce this by putting a unique index on document_id + keyword in your keywords table