# Select correct MySQL record with multiple records

Tags: mysql

I have a pain finding the correct MySQL statement.

Records are like

```
id    leadid    fieldnumber    value
1     1         100            AAA
2     1         101            yes
3     1         102            email1
4     2         100            AAA
5     2         101            no
6     2         102            email2
7     3         100            BBB
8     3         101            yes
9     3         102            email3
10    4         100            AAA
11    4         101            yes
12    4         102            email4
```

Now I want to collect from every unique leadid the value column from the record with fieldnumber = 102 where the corresponding records with the same leadid satisfy:

```
(fieldnumber = 100 AND value = "AAA") AND 
(fieldnumber = 101 AND value = "yes")
```

In this example this results in: email1, email4

I got already result with the first selection statement (`fieldnumber = 100 AND value = "AAA"`) but when I add the second one (`fieldnumber = 101 AND value = "yes"`), the result is always zero records.

I suppose it's a stupid thing, but I can't figure out or find the correct statement to do so.

Comment: Sounds like EAV which [is bad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20782760/difference-between-two-table-structure/20783125#20783125)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  When you ask SQL questions, please make sure you identify your tables by name so that people don't have to invent names for you.  It is a surprisingly common mistake in SQL questions on SO (so you're not the first person to do it, and you won't be the last, but please don't do it again).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key point here is to recognize that you are working with three records from the same table at the same time.  You have to join the table with itself, twice — these are called *self-joins*.

You need something like:

```
SELECT a3.value
  FROM Anonymous_Table AS a1
  JOIN Anonymous_Table AS a2 ON a1.leadid = a2.leadid
  JOIN Anonymous_Table AS a3 ON a1.leadid = a3.leadid
 WHERE (a1.fieldnumber = 100 AND a1.value = "AAA")
   AND (a2.fieldnumber = 101 AND a2.value = "yes")
   AND (a3.fieldnumber = 102)
```

Comment: How many self-joins can you do? when having more than 4, there're no results anymore. I just add some more "ax.fieldnummer = number" to have more info per record the query return

Comment: There is probably no specific limit — you self-join as often as you need to.  Unless you are actually a computer, you are likely to get bored, or make a mistake, writing the self-joins before you run out of capacity.  Realistically, you could reasonably expect to be able to do of the order of 100 self-joins, and quite possibly more, but you'd probably want to start questioning what you're up to.  If you are using many self-joins, you might want to add the filter conditions to the ON clauses: `JOIN Anonymous_Table AS a2 ON a1.leadid = a2.leadid AND (a2.fieldnumber = 101 AND a2.value = "yes")`.

Comment: You updated the comment while I was typing… If you are running into 'no more results', then you might conceivably be running into a bug in your DBMS.  You'd need to show the data (presumably 5 rows) and the query you're using.  And you'd demonstrate that the 4-join version of the query returns data and the 5-join version doesn't.  You'll also ensure you're using the latest stable version of the DBMS; it is probably the best one to use.

Comment: current db is v5.5.31, tested on v5.6.17 ... but same result