# How to search in an EAV table plus another MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, entity-attribute-value

I am trying to make a query to find records in an EAV table `keywords` and in the `documents`table, with OR statement, but it gives me repeated results:

```
SELECT d.id, d.name, d.created, d.updated 
FROM documents d 
INNER JOIN permissions p ON (d.wfid = p.wfId AND d.docid = p.docId AND p.userid = 1)
INNER JOIN keywords k0 ON (k0.document_id = d.id AND (k0.value IN('Pérez, Gabriel', 
  'DOC1') OR d.name IN ('Pérez, Gabriel', 'DOC1') ))
ORDER BY d.id DESC;

+------+------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id   | name | created             | updated             |
+------+------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 5267 | DOC1 | 2014-03-07 11:41:23 | 2014-02-25 12:39:10 |
| 5267 | DOC1 | 2014-03-07 11:41:23 | 2014-02-25 12:39:10 |
| 5267 | DOC1 | 2014-03-07 11:41:23 | 2014-02-25 12:39:10 |
| 5266 | DOC1 | 2014-03-07 11:41:23 | 2014-03-06 01:35:16 |
| 5266 | DOC1 | 2014-03-07 11:41:23 | 2014-03-06 01:35:16 |
| 5266 | DOC1 | 2014-03-07 11:41:23 | 2014-03-06 01:35:16 |
| 5265 | DOC1 | 2014-03-07 11:41:23 | 2014-02-25 12:38:37 |
| 5265 | DOC1 | 2014-03-07 11:41:23 | 2014-02-25 12:38:37 |
| 5265 | DOC1 | 2014-03-07 11:41:23 | 2014-02-25 12:38:37 |
| 5264 | DOC1 | 2014-03-07 11:41:23 | 2014-02-25 12:38:25 |
| 5264 | DOC1 | 2014-03-07 11:41:23 | 2014-02-25 12:38:25 |
| 5264 | DOC1 | 2014-03-07 11:41:23 | 2014-02-25 12:38:25 |
| 5263 | DOC1 | 2014-04-07 11:23:00 | 2014-03-20 09:54:30 |
| 5263 | DOC1 | 2014-04-07 11:23:00 | 2014-03-20 09:54:30 |
| 5263 | DOC1 | 2014-04-07 11:23:00 | 2014-03-20 09:54:30 |
+------+------+---------------------+---------------------+
15 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If I use `SELECT DISTINCT`

```
+------+-----------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id   | name                        | created             | updated             |
+------+-----------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 5355 | Documento - Digitalización  | 2014-03-31 12:57:51 | 2014-03-31 12:57:51 |
| 5354 | Documento - Digitalización  | 2014-03-28 11:14:11 | 2014-03-28 11:14:11 |
| 5267 | DOC1                        | 2014-03-07 11:41:23 | 2014-02-25 12:39:10 |
| 5266 | DOC1                        | 2014-03-07 11:41:23 | 2014-03-06 01:35:16 |
| 5265 | DOC1                        | 2014-03-07 11:41:23 | 2014-02-25 12:38:37 |
| 5264 | DOC1                        | 2014-03-07 11:41:23 | 2014-02-25 12:38:25 |
| 5263 | DOC1                        | 2014-04-07 11:23:00 | 2014-03-20 09:54:30 |
+------+-----------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Then I get what I want.

My questions are:

1) Why is the first duplicating rows?

2) Is bad to use SELECT DISTINCT or it helps the performance?

3) Is my query bad written? I need to search the entered values in both, document table and keywords table, to see if there is a match (like a Google search)

```
mysql> describe documents;
+---------+-----------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field   | Type      | Null | Key | Default             | Extra                       |
+---------+-----------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
| id      | int(11)   | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment              |
| name    | char(100) | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| wfid    | char(50)  | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| docid   | char(50)  | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| created | timestamp | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                             |
| updated | timestamp | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+---------+-----------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe keywords;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| document_id | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| keyword     | char(50)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| value       | varchar(250) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: It's not because your query bad-written. It's because your database structure is [bad-designed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20782760/difference-between-two-table-structure/20783125#20783125)

Comment: @AlmaDo I know its bad, Its something I have to live with, until I make a second version I have to maintain this code :(

Comment: Who is el Señor Peréz ? and why is his name occurring in both names and  values?

Comment: @OllieJones, because In the search,you can enter values like in Google, for example: `StackOverflow MySql`, and because the data can be Document Name or Keyword Value, it must be searched in both tables

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to discern the exact form of your keywords table from your question, so this answer might be incorrect.

But, usually a keywords (name/value pairs) table can be accessed like this, to retrieve just one keyword's value.

```
 SELECT d.id, d.name, d.created, d.updated, 
        k0.value AS doc1_value,
        k1.value AS doc2_value 
   FROM documents AS d
   LEFT JOIN keywords AS k0 ON k0.document_id = d.id AND k0.name = 'DOC1'
   LEFT JOIN keywords AS k1 ON k1.document_id = d.id AND k1.name = 'DOC2'
```

This will retrieve the value of the keyword attributes with names DOC1 and DOC2 for each document. Use the LEFT JOIN to deal with the case where the particular document might lack the keyword value.

Are you looking for a document which has any attribute containing a particular value?  In that case you may need to do this:

```
 SELECT d.id, d.name, d.created, d.updated, 
        k0.value AS doc1_value,
        k1.value AS doc2_value 
   FROM documents AS d
   JOIN keywords AS sk ON sk.document_id = d.id AND sk.value = 'Pérez, Gabriel'
   LEFT JOIN keywords AS k0 ON k0.document_id = d.id AND k0.name = 'DOC1'
   LEFT JOIN keywords AS k1 ON k1.document_id = d.id AND k1.name = 'DOC2'
```

Notice the use of the JOIN rather than LEFT JOIN, to exclude nonmatching rows.

Comment: Thanks Ollie, sorry for not being very clear, I've updated my question with table description. I will not be searching `keywords.name`, only `keywords.value`, and `document.name`. So If I search DOC1, it surely will be on `document.name` but since I can't know that, I must look in both `keywords.value` and `document.name` for each word I enter in the simple search and retrieve those documents_id with a match