# Data Management - a lot of fields

Tags: mysql, database, csv, database-design

I want to create a Data Management system that allow me to upload many CSV to the database and  view the data, compare field to field from other source/csv. We get many CSV from a lot companies all the time.  The purpose of Data Management system is to view the data, compare and amend the data only.

Problem is that many CSV will have many different column and number of columns.

I don't create each mysql table to match CSV fields.. that is not very efficient.

Should I use EAV database design model or what is better solution and simple?

Comment: Do not use EAV. It may have use-cases, but in general, [it's awful](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20783125/2637490). Better design your DB to avoid this. Normally, if you have too many attributes - then, probably, you're mixing two or more entities in one domain

Comment: @AlmaDo So what to use apart from EAV?

Comment: As I've said: you should first check - if all of your entities properties _really_ belong to them. For example: user and his address, where user can have home, work and other addresses. First attempt is to mix all in one table, while proper attempt is - to create "user_addresses" table and make a reference from address to user (may be, even more, create "locations", "addresses", "user_addresses" tables - but that depends from certain case and may be over-engineering in simple issue)

Comment: @AlmaDo I understand what you are saying but it is not that simple. The fields from CSV can be completely random from many sources and the tables or fields might not be existed in MySQL database.

Comment: It seems you're trying to make dynamic the thing, which is intended to be static (i.e. database structure). No good may come from that. In that case your issue may be outside relational DBMS at all, since they must have static structure to use "relations" (as it states from "RDBMS").

Comment: Who is in charge of the conceptual model?  Who matches CSV fields up with named and defined data items?  How do you expect to compare data that came from different providers?  If each provider has their own model of the data, you may be stuck with nothing better than EAV.  Good luck with that!