# How to improve the performance of EAV Model database in mysql

Tags: mysql, performance, entity-attribute-value

I have database with eav model tables .database is growing day by day so it is difficult to search and generating the reports. can any one suggest me the optimization steps for generating reports

Comment: You can try sharding. However, I would advise to create appropriate indexes(on attribute_id) so that lookup in fast.

Comment: There is only one way to improve EAV: throw it away. It's [bad by design](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20782760/difference-between-two-table-structure/20783125#20783125) (see the reasons of why it's impossible to "improve" it in that answer)