# Database design for variable number of attributes

Tags: database, oracle, data-modeling

I am trying to come up with a schema for an Oracle db. The problem is as follows:

The database should represent an attribute (- say a url) associated with a variety of attributes for a variety of values.

For Example:

The database should have the mapping:

```
If attribute-X has value-X ==> Url-X
If attribute-Y has value-Y ==> Url-Y
If attribute-X has value-X && attribute-Y has value-Y ==> Url-XY
```

Also the number of attributes is not defined, so these cannot correspond to a attribute in the db.

The workaround I have thought is to store it as a multi name value-pair and use the same to look up in the database.

For example:

```
**attribute**            **Key**                  **Value**

attribute-X              value-X                    Url-X

attribute-Y              value-Y                    Url-Y

attribute-X&attribute-Y  value-X&value-Y            Url-XY
```

I am new to databases and I am aware that is is not a neat representation of the data model. Is there a better way to represent this ?

Comment: Do *not* use EAV, which is explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20782760/difference-between-two-table-structure) . If you really need the structure with attributes, take a look into document-oriented DBMS (which are particular case of non-relational DBMS).

Answer (score 0):

You could model this with one table, but then you would need to keep adding attributes (new column for each new attribute), which is not a good design.

You can however, model this so you can add attributes types, then add the attribute dynamically.
[image]